# What is they syntax to return a match in a subquery inside a CASE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is they syntax to return a match in a subquery and if one is not found, return the original result.  This is the closest example I can think of.  I tried using coalesce as well.

```
SELECT bla,foo,
CASE WHEN bar IN (SELECT bar2 from table) THEN bar2 else bar end as 'bar'
FROM otherTable
```

This my attempt at showing an example:

```
foo  |  bar  | bar2
--------------------
  1  |  xxxx | x
  2  |  xxxx | xx
  3  |  x    | 
  4  |  xxx  |
```

If bar in bar2 then bar2 else bar.

Comment: would be really good to have some sample data for both tables and expected output.  there are some different possible interpretations of your question

Comment: They'd always be the same, is there some other field that would relate the two tables together?

Comment: @hart not always the same; the case is returning the *local* column bar2 if bar exists in the bar2 column of the other table, otherwise the raw value. There are better way to write this query though.

Comment: I don't know really know a better way to explain.  If bar in bar2 table, then show bar2 else show bar?  Bar2 table has about 24 records, where bar the outside query has potentially thousands.  Can you direct on a better way to write this that I might be able to figure out for myself?

Comment: Sample data and your desired result would explain it better.

Comment: Does `bar2` exist in both tables? If `bar` and `bar2` exist in `otherTable` and you just want to choose which one gets returned, then your logic should be doing that already.

Comment: @HartCO bar2 sometimes exists in both tables.  If it does it exist in both tables I want it to return the value from table, otherwise just return bar from otherTable.

Comment: is there a relation between 2 tables?

Comment: @McNets not besides that x is in both tables.  "table" has only one column other than ID.  So bar can return many results, I only want bar2 if it matches in bar otherwise just bar.  I have tried other options like joining but there is no unique identifier other than the "x"s so joining returns no results or too many results.

Comment: But, how many rows returns: `WHEN bar in (SELECT bar2 from table) then bar2 else bar` <== in fact `bar2 = bar`

Comment: @McNets.. Well, none.. If i use bar2. and all of them if use I bar (in the then bar2 else part).  Is it not possible to return the result from the inner query to the outer query?

Comment: One thing to note:  I have switched around the then / else portions and it seems to always fail to else.  I replaced 'else bar end as bar' with 'else null end as bar' and it returns null (multiple times).  But if I run (SELECT bar2 from table) I see the matching result in there.

Comment: If (bar in bar2) doesn't return nothing, it's a comparison. it's a boolean expression. `CASE WHEN bar IN (SELECT bar2 from table) THEN (select bar2 from table) else bar end as bar`, but if bar2 returns more than one result it is not possible.

Comment: @McNets.  You are right.  Even as a boolean, it doesn't hit the 'then' portion.  I must be doing something else wrong too, but my goal is to return the result from (select bar2 from table), perhaps the whole statement is incorrect for that purpose. If you want to submit your last response as an answer, I will accept it.  Thank you.

Comment: you need something  like (select bar2 from table where smth = smth else), but then a JOIN clause is preferred.

Comment: For an example we can work with, show both tables and the desired output.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, McNets got me going the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a non valid sentence due: `bar in (select bar2 from tt2)` acts as a boolean expression, bar2 is not returned to the query.

```
select foo,
       case when bar in (select bar2 from tt2) then bar2 else bar end as bar
from tt1;
```

> Invalid column name 'bar2'.

This could be valid if '(select bar2 from tt2)' returns only 1 value

```
select foo,
       case when bar in (select bar2 from tt2) then (select bar2 from tt2) else bar end as bar
from tt1;
```

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

This works, but I'm not sure it is what you want:

```
select foo,
       case when bar in (select bar2 from tt2) then (select top 1 bar2 from tt2) else bar end as bar
from tt1;
```

Play with it here: http://rextester.com/UGZA86889

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around the alias, ie `as 'bar'` -> `as bar`:

```
SELECT bla, foo,
CASE WHEN bar IN (SELECT bar2 from table) THEN bar2 else bar end as bar
FROM otherTable
```

Comment: single-quotes for column-aliases shouldn't be a problem in SQL Server, which i guess the OP is using.